# How to receive data in root component with method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to understand how Vue works.
What I am trying approach is simply to receive number '1' with method in Vue.
Code execution gives me 'undefined'. Why?

```
<div id="form">
    <button v-on:click="submitProduct">Save</button>
</div>
<script>
    var someForm = Vue.createApp ({
    methods: {
        submitBtn: function(){
            someForm.showdata
        },
        showData: function(){
            return 1
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: you're not returning and not invoking the function, you should learn more JS before jumping into vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign the returned data to a variable then show it using alert or console.log a,d use `this` instead of `someForm`:

```
    var someForm = Vue.createApp ({
    methods: {
        submitBtn: function(){
          let data=  this.showData();
           alert(data);
        },
        showData: function(){
            return 1
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Shows me following: Uncaught TypeError: this.showdata is not a function

Comment: it's `this.showData()` not `this.showdata()` with uppercased D

Comment: Sorry, I'm losing focus! :(  But your code worked! :))